# Extjs 4.1 pagingtoolbar default page

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to change default page of pagination toolbar to 1 of 1 instead 0 of 0 in case of no record.Plus I am not using store proxy to request any records, so is there any way to accomplish it without using store proxy. According to my requirement user can add rows manually to the grid with the pagination toolbar showing page 1 and when rows exceeds 10 it moves to 2nd page.

Comment: Please split this into two distinct questions.  One about the paging display and one about the requirement to move to another page when adding rows.  Lumping them all together like this makes it feel like: "Here's my requirements, solve it for me."

Comment: You should provide example code for what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ext it is possible to overload a component like Ext.toolbar.Paging with your own custom version. Simply specify an alias in your definition and you can us it just like the "native control."

In order to be sure that the approach would work, I set up a test project with a simple datasource and implemented enough of a replacement definition that I could see the "Ext.toolbar.Paging".getPagingItems method being fired in my custom definition.

From that point you can replace the code inside the definition of the original method to allow for a custom minimum in addition to the opportunity to overload the "updateInfo" method to make sure that during data reloads you're not plowing through your customizations.

In addition to these two things, you should (with a relatively small amount of effort) be able to implement on top of the control to support dynamically changing it's values based on the contents of your grid.

If you look at the documentation for ux.data.PagingStore you should be able to suss out the differences in using a remotely supplied store from something that is served with data locally.

Hope this helps you.

Code Sample:

```
Ext.define(
    "Test.view.testview.TvPageBar",
    {
        extend: "Ext.toolbar.Paging",
        alias: "widget.tvpagebar",
        title: "Bob",
        strictInit: function () {
            "use strict";
            console.log("TvPageBar init");
        },
        getPagingItems: function () {
            console.log("getPagingItems", this);
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },
        initComponent: function () {
            this.strictInit();
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
);
```